# Bad values in inputs - no proper UTF-8 encoding? Tomcat?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

### HTML Code:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

### Hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
<property name="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />
```

When I save in form: ółąćźżóąłćżóaó (polish letters) in base its look like this:

```
`ó&#322;&#261;&#263;&#378;&#380;ó&#261;&#322;&#263;&#380;óaó`
```

So I think its great but problem is when I want for example edit this from HTML form I have:

[image: This is text but not encoded in UTF8]

This is text but not encoded in UTF-8 what is wrong ? I use bootsrap.css

I find out that my form is giving already escaped HTML maybe its tomcat problem ?

Comment: You seem to save escaped HTML text... How exactly do you read that text, save it and then reread it?

Comment: These are [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). This is not an encoding problem. Some library you are using is (correctly) escaping your text.

Comment: Here is my service: https://gist.github.com/spec8320/e27be113e7719ee35386

Comment: This only answers the part on how you read the code. Please add the code you use to read the text from the server and save it in the question.

Comment: Added controller persistance in post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```